# Delete ArchiveManager configuration

Tags: 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion, archive-manager-1-sp3

New license file does not have Archive manager on CM server, when I deploy the page it complains cannot find license for archive manager. We are not using archive manager and would like to remove all existing configuration of archive manager. Can you Please suggest where all I need to update?

I tried updating cd_storage_config.xml file and deleted cd_archivemanager_conf.xml file, but not the deployer complains "can't find configuration file : cd_archivemanager_conf.xml".

Please suggest what am I missing.

Comment: Thakur , please check the link https://docs.rws.com/792471/126901/sdl-archive-manager-1-0-sp3/configuring-content-deployer and see if you can comment the configuration and see if it helps

Comment: thanks a lot @AnandNS This resolved my issue.

Comment: Thakur accept the Answer so it will be useful for others

Answer (score 4):

Remove  the following  elements to the cd_deployer_conf.xml as the first  element in the list:

> 

```
 <Module Type="DeploymentPipelineModule" Class="com.tridion.archiving.modules.DeploymentPipelineModule">
 <Pipeline Name="archiving-pipeline-initial" InitialState="" FinalState="current-urls" />
    </Module>
```

Remove  the following  to the cd_deployer_conf.xml as the last  element in the list:

> 

```
    <Module Type="DeploymentPipelineModule" Class="com.tridion.archiving.modules.DeploymentPipelineModule">
            <Pipeline Name="archiving-pipeline" InitialState="" FinalState=""/>
    </Module>
```

Refer to this 
[Link](https://docs.rws.com/792471/126901/sdl-archive-manager-1-0-sp3/configuring-content-deployer)